# Find $\frac{a^2}{2a^2+bc}+\frac{b^2}{2b^2+ac}+\frac{c^2}{2c^2+ab}$ if $a+b+c=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck at this algebra problem, it seems to me that's what's provided doesn't even at all.

Provided:  $$a+b+c=0$$

Find the value of:  $$\frac{a^2}{2a^2+bc}+\frac{b^2}{2b^2+ac}+\frac{c^2}{2c^2+ab}$$

Like I'm not sure where to start, and the provided clue doesn't even make sense.  There's no way I can think of to factor this big polynomial into a form like $a\times p+b\times q+c\times r=s$ where $p,q,r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean minimum/maximum value?

Comment: What happens when you put $b=c$? What does that tell you about this expression? And if you put $a=0$?

Comment: yes, but I thought we shouldn't just assign variables to a given equation unless you can prove that the polynomial above always give the same value

Comment: But it can give you a good idea what the solution you're looking for might look like. Assigning values or looking at special cases is often a good way to build up some intuition, especially if you're stuck with a problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note that:
$$\frac{a^2}{2a^2+bc}=\frac{a^2}{a^2+a(-b-c)+bc}=\frac{a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}$$
This applies in the same way for:
$$\frac{b^2}{2b^2+ac}=\frac{b^2}{(b-c)(b-a)}\ \text{and}\ \frac{c^2}{2c^2+ab}=\frac{c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}$$Therefore, the original equation is equal to:
\begin{align}
&\frac{a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{b^2}{(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac{c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)}
\\
\\
&=\frac{-a^2(b-c)-b^2(c-a)-c^2(a-b)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}
\\
\\
&=\frac{-a^2b-b^2c-c^2a+a^2c+b^2a+c^2b}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}
\\
\\
&=\frac{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}
\\
\\
&=\boxed{1}
\end{align}

Comment: How do you factorize $-a^2b-b^2c-c^2a+a^2c+b^2a+c^2b$ to $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$

Comment: you can expand out the denominator instead to get 1.

Answer (score 0):

$$ −a^2b−b^2c−c^2a+a^2c+b^2a+c^2b  
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
\\ 
\overset{\tiny{+abc-abc}}{=} 
\Big[ abc+bc^2-b^2c-ac^2 \Big] 
+ 
\Big[ -a^2b-abc+ab^2+a^2c \Big] 
\\ 
=c(ab+bc-b^2-ac)-a(ab+bc-b^2-ac) 
\\ 
=(c-a)(ab+bc-b^2-ac) 
\\ 
=(c-a)(a-b)(b-c) 
. $$