# Solving $L= \frac{a^2}{2a^2+bc}+\frac{b^2}{2b^2+ac}+\frac{c^2}{2c^2+ab}$ priveded $a+b+c=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, rational-functions

> Let $a,b,c$ be such that $a+b+c=0$ and suppose that 
>   $$L= \frac{a^2}{2a^2+bc}+\frac{b^2}{2b^2+ac}+\frac{c^2}{2c^2+ab}.$$
>   Find the value of $L$.

I can only see the symmetry of these function but cannot solve it.

Comment: this is the most generic title ever... "solve math"

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393786/find-fraca22a2bc-fracb22b2ac-fracc22c2ab-if-abc-0

Answer (score 0):

Since $a+b+c|(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc)$, $a+b+c = 0 \implies a^3+b^3+c^3 = 3abc$.

Then Wolfram Alpha says that this gives the sum as $1$.

Comment: More explicitly, $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ = $(a+b+c)(a^2-ab+b^2-bc+c^2-ac)$ in general.

Comment: i cant understand ur solution....please expain....\\

Answer (score 0):

Since $a+b+c=0$ it follows $c=-a-b$, then 
\begin{align}
2a^2+bc&=2a^2+b(-a-b)\\
&=2a^2-ab-b^2\\
&=(a-b)(2a+b)\\
&=(a-b)(a+a+b)\\
&=(a-b)(a-c)\quad\text{because $a+b=-c$}
\end{align}
In a similar way we can obtain $2b^2+ac=(b-a)(b-c)$ and $2c^2+ab=(c-a)(c-b)$. Then
\begin{align}
L&=\frac{a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{b^2}{(b-a)(b-c)}+\frac{c^2}{(c-a)(c-b)} \\
&=\frac{a^2}{(a-b)(a-c)}-\frac{b^2}{(a-b)(b-c)}+\frac{c^2}{(a-c)(b-c)} \\
&=\frac{a^2(b-c)-b^2(a-c)+c^2(a-b)}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)} \\
&=\frac{-a(b^2-c^2)+b(a^2-c^2)-c(a^2-b^2)}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)} \\
&=\frac{-a(b+c)(b-c)+b(a+c)(a-c)-c(a+b)(a-b)}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)} \\
&=\frac{-a(b+c)(b-c)+b(a+c)(a-c)-c(a+b)[(a-c)-(b-c)]}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)} \\
&=\frac{[-a(b+c)+c(a+b)](b-c)+[b(a+c)-c(a+b)](a-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)} \\
&=\frac{-b(a-c)(b-c)+a(b-c)(a-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)} \\
&=\frac{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)} \\
&=1
\end{align}